# How does this fluid-fill stop mechanism work?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, design

I bought an interesting shaped water fill-stop valve from ebay a while ago.  Very convenient form factor, even though there was some forward pressure requirement.

I want to now make a custom version of this device on the 3D printer, since my current use case needs to be able to handle a large degree of FOD without stopping.  When I took the device apart I was quite surprised by the actions of the mechanism.  There is a float at the bottom that actuates an arm, which then plugs a hole, which leads to a spring-plunger system somehow stopping the flow of water through the system.

While I probably wont be able to replicate this on the 3D printer after all (unless I get creative with TPU), I am still quite curious.  How does this device stop the water?  Specifically, how does the tiny hole getting plugged by the arm, lead to the plunger rising into the center outlet hole?  I am not able to replicate the functioning device until it is fully assembled.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: google `irrigation valve`

Comment: @jsotola its close but not quite the same operating principle unless that tiny hole that the spring is pricked through actually lets in some water from the inlet annulus.  Maybe it does, but I assumed it was water tight....

Comment: And what makes you think you can't 3d print? The principle should be pretty simple to understand when you CAD it and look at a cross section of the operational motions.  There are probably a good amount of patents that would help too...

Comment: Will you be stealing their patent?

Comment: @SolarMike nobody said you need to look at the current patents.

Comment: And Solar Mike, that is precisely why I did not link any. The op is already asking to reverse engineer from someone else's product.  Not all that different from stealing their patent, as patents apply even if a violator arrived at it independently, but that'd be one for the patent lawyers if it ever gets there rather than here.

Comment: @Abel The flexible spring membrane system would be challenging for me to manufacture at home.  I certainly could not 3D print if if I copied it 1 for 1, nor would 1-for-1 work since I need larger diameter outlet so lets throw that discussion point out...

Comment: There is a beautiful rubber known to vulcanize at room temperature  with exposure to moisture (search RTV) that would do pretty well to make membranes.  You may know the cheap stuff as what you caulk bathrooms with.  More expensive variants exist that can take high temperatures or resist fuel and oil that can be used to make custom (automotive) gaskets and seals.